# Quick-add quoatation marks at the ends of each line in R

Tags: r

I really just wanted to be able to comment out this code by highlighting it all and some key commands, like the comment button in excel and the ctrl+shift+/ in SAS, changing this:

```
date = c(2014-10-23
     2014-10-23
     2014-10-23
     2014-10-23
     2014-10-24
     2014-10-24
     2014-10-24
     2014-10-24
     2014-10-24
     2014-10-24
     2014-10-24
     2014-10-24
     2014-10-24
     2014-10-24
     2014-10-24
     2014-10-24
     2014-10-24
     2014-10-24)
```

to this:

```
#date = c(2014-10-23
     #2014-10-23
     #2014-10-23
     #2014-10-23
     #2014-10-24
     #2014-10-24
     #2014-10-24
     #2014-10-24
     #2014-10-24
     #2014-10-24
     #2014-10-24
     #2014-10-24
     #2014-10-24
     #2014-10-24
     #2014-10-24
     #2014-10-24
     #2014-10-24
     #2014-10-24)
```

It turns out the answer is ctrl+shift+c. Thanks for your help!

Comment: On the other hand, maybe you just want, `read.table(text="vector over many lines")`

Comment: The only problem I have witht that is what would the delimiter be?

Comment: `read.table` works for the example given. For space-delimited data on a single line, I use `qw = function(s) unlist(strsplit(s,' '))`. If you wanted one function to cover both cases, you could switch `' '` to a more general whitespace-catcher (looking up what you need in R's regex documentation).